# sudo ./pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/data start,error:Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/libpq.5.dylib

Tags: linux, postgresql, macos, edb

My system is macOS 10.15.7

I installed postgresql-9.5 from EDB.When the installation is complete, I executed the following command:

`cd /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin`

`sudo ./pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/data start`

An error occur

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/./pg_ctl
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/./../lib/libpq.5.dylib: code signing blocked mmap() of '/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/./../lib/libpq.5.dylib'
    /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/./../lib/libpq.5.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1
    /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/../lib/libpq.5.dylib: code signing blocked mmap() of '/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/../lib/libpq.5.dylib'
    /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/../lib/libpq.5.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1
    file system relative paths not allowed in hardened programs
zsh: abort      ./pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/data start
```

The related soft connections are as follows：

/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib

`-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  daemon    384752  2 10 14:07 libpq.5.8.dylib`

`lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   daemon       15  3 20 16:54 libpq.5.dylib -> libpq.5.8.dylib`

/usr/local/lib

`lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   admin   41  3 21 23:38 libpq.5.dylib -> /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/libpq.5.dylib`

Please help me,thanks everyone.

Comment: The PG 9.5 is certified only on 10.8 - 10.10. It is better to use a supported version for your OS, which is PG13 for mac OS version 10.13 - 10.15

Comment: @Amjad Shahzad I still don't have a definite answer to this question, but I found another way to solve it.Download the **postgres.app** from https://postgresapp.com/downloads.html and chose the `Postgres.app with all currently supported versions`.Start postgresql server in mac os according to https://postgresapp.com. And the PG9.5 can certified macos 10.15.7